# Apache Http - Getting Duplicate Cache-Control in my Response Headers

Tags: apache, caching

I am setting Cache-Control in the httpd.conf where i also have Mellon SSO Configuration. I am getting two cache-control included in the response headers. So i have commented out the **MellonEnable "info**" and restarted the apache. Now my Cache-Control got reflected and now it is only mine. But this is not an exact solution to turn off/override the cache-control, so i find out that there is an option that controls whether the Cache-control header is sent back in responses in Mellon configuration.

So i have given **MellonSendCacheControlHeader Off** in the conf file, but the apache is throwing issue like "Invalid command 'MellonSendCacheControlHeader', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to Update the Answer.

Actually the latest Mellon version 0.13.0 have the fix. Here there is a fix to "*Allow disabling the Cache-Control HTTP response header*". So the duplicate Cache-Control will be avoided, if we set the **MellonSendCacheControlHeader Off** in the conf file.

Un-install the older version of Mellon and install the version 0.13.0 and update the conf file with the configuration **MellonSendCacheControlHeader Off**. Restart the Apache Server once all changes done. It will work.